# how to make online radio of local fm station

Tags: javascript

how to make online radio of the local radio station

Answer (score 1):

"Not a real question", but here's something to read: [How to Create Your Own Internet Radio Station](http://radio.about.com/od/createinternetradio/a/How-to-Create-Your-Own-Internet-Radio-Station_3.htm)